# Qual é o equivalente de "from" e "import" (PYTHON) em Ruby?

Tags: python-3.x, ruby

Gostaria de chamar um script através de outro script.
Em Python eu uso os comandos "from" e "import", mas qual comando seria equivalente para fazer isso em Ruby?

Comment: Não é o `require` detalhado na [documentação de módulos](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para incluir módulos, classes, etc em outros arquivos você tem que usar o `require_relative` ou `require` (`require_relative` é um jeito mais "rúbico" de programar.) Por exemplo o seguinte módulo:

```
module Format

  def cor_verde(input)
    puts"\e[32m#{input}[0m\e"
  end
end
```

Então você tem o seguinte arquivo:

```
require_relative "format" #<= "pede" o arquivo

include Format #<= inclui o módulo

def exemplo
  cor_verde("Essa frase vai ser verde") #<= chama a formatação
end
```

A mesma coisa para classes:

```
class Exemplo

  attr_accessor :input

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input
  end

  def prompt
    print "#{@input}: "
    gets.chomp
  end
end

exemplo = Exemplo.new(ARGV[0])
```

E então o arquivo main:

```
require_relative "class_exemplo"

exemplo.prompt
```

Para chamar qualquer classe ou módulo a partir de outro arquivo você tem que dar o `require`.

Comment: +1! Uma pequena observação: quando está se utilizando Ruby on Rails, tudo que está dentro das subpastas de `app/` é automaticamente requerido por padrão (com algumas exceções), sem precisar chamar o `require`.